# icefaces ace components have a big fonts

Tags: icefaces-3

i am using icefaces 3 .
I have all my ace components displayed properly with css, but the only problem is all my ace components have a big font size and big size.

the size is much bigger compared to the size of the components shown in the icefaces showcase.

Can someone please shed some light on what could be causing this problem.

Comment: Can some one please help

Comment: I don't know how to change all components with a single css change, but you can change the font-size of individual components by using the style attribute (style="font-size:10px;")

Comment: Thanks fs for replying, providing a style for fontsize for each component will help for the timebeing. but if i can get it done in one shot for all teh components then it will be better. Any idea ?